# Dagger 2: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] cannot solve this one

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I get a `[Dagger/MissingBinding]` error and I can not figure out why on this error.

Here is the full error stack:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.io.File cannot be provided without
>   an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. java.io.File
>   is injected at service.KeyStoreService(keyStoreFile)
>   service.KeyStoreService is injected at
>   di.Module.WalletRepositoryModule.getWalletRepository(…,
>   keyStoreService) repository.WalletRepositoryInterface is provided at
>   di.component.ApplicationComponent.getWalletRepository()
>
> The following
>   other entry points also depend on it:
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
>   [di.component.ApplicationComponent ?
>   di.Module.BindModule_BindStartModule.StartActivitySubcomponent]
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
>   [di.component.ApplicationComponent ?
>   di.Module.BindModule_BindAddWalletActivity.AddWalletActivitySubcomponent]

KeyStoreService class:

```
public class KeyStoreService implements KeyStoreServiceInterface {

    private final KeyStore keyStore;

    @Inject
    public KeyStoreService(File keyStoreFile) {
        keyStore = new KeyStore(keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath(), Geth.LightScryptN, Geth.LightScryptP);
    }
}
```

WalletRepositoryModule class:

```
@Module
public class WalletRepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    WalletRepositoryInterface getWalletRepository(SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper, KeyStoreService keyStoreService){
        return new WalletRepository(sharedPreferencesHelper, keyStoreService);
    }

}
```

ApplicationComponent class:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ApplicationContextModule.class,
        SharedPreferencesModule.class,
        KeyStoreModule.class,
        SharedPreferenceHelperModule.class,
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AndroidsupportInjectionModule.class,
        WalletRepositoryModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MyApplication myApplication);
        ApplicationComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);

    @ApplicationContext
    Context getApplicationContext();

    SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences();

    KeyStoreServiceInterface getKeyStoreService();

    SharedPreferencesHelper getSharedPreferencesHelper();

    WalletRepositoryInterface getWalletRepository();

}
```

All the other modules are/was working. It's only after adding WalletRepositoryModule I got this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some people stumbling upon this from Google might have the same problem I did: Lombok can be very inconsistent in its compatibility with Dagger. If you're _generating_ the injected constructor, always start troubleshooting by writing out the constructor manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to tell Dagger how to resolve `File`. I would suggest you a `@Provides` `@Named` annotated method. EG

```
  @Provides
  @Named("KEY_STORE_FILE") 
  public File provideKeyStoreFile() {
     return new File(path/to/keystore)
  }
```

and change

```
@Inject
public KeyStoreService(File keyStoreFile) {
```

in

```
@Inject
public KeyStoreService(@Named("KEY_STORE_FILE") File keyStoreFile) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I worked. Just some quick follow up questions, if you have time. 
Why did this error occur after adding WalletrepositoryModule and not before that? It didnt need to be "@Named" ealier and did not throw any errors.
Could I use Qualifier instead of "@Named", and could I take care of the naming/qualifying in the modules instead so I don't have to have "@Named/@Qualifier" in my Keystoreservice class?

Comment: because `WalletRepositoryInterface` has `KeyStoreService` as dependency. You could use an annotated `@Provides` method that returns a `KeyStoreService` dependencies. In the method you will have to call the `new KeyStoreService` manually

Comment: Thanks once again!